# The Euler-Lagrange first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to calculate $\frac{d\phi}{dz}$ from following equation:

$$A\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}+\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)=0,$$ where $A$ is a constant?

Answer (score 6):

<s>The trick is to integrate the equation once; up to an integration constant, you will get</s>

```
Integrate[A D[ϕ[z], z, z] + Cos[z] Sin[z], z] == C
```

> $A \phi '(z)-\frac{\cos ^2(z)}{2}=C$

## Edit

I overlooked the equation should be

```
A D[ϕ[z], z, z] + Cos[ϕ[z]] Sin[ϕ[z]] == 0
```

No problem. Essentially, the same trick works *after* multiplication with `D[ϕ[z], z]`:

```
Integrate[A D[ϕ[z], z, z] D[ϕ[z], z] + Cos[ϕ[z]] Sin[ϕ[z]] D[ϕ[z], z], z] == C
Solve[eq, D[ϕ[z], z]]
```

> $\frac{1}{2} A \phi '(z)^2-\frac{1}{2} \cos ^2(\phi (z))=C$
>
> $\left\{\left\{\phi '(z)\to -\frac{\sqrt{2 C+\cos ^2(\phi
>    (z))}}{\sqrt{A}}\right\},\left\{\phi '(z)\to \frac{\sqrt{2 C+\cos
>    ^2(\phi (z))}}{\sqrt{A}}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: What a simple solution!

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich!

Comment: @Henrik:
your solution is wrong, as the second part of the equation is Sin[phi] Cos[phi]
i.e. functions of `phi`, not simply of `z`. That means it is not the derivative of `Cos[phi]^2`, as is missing the `d phi/dz` part. Briefly, it won't work.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Hmm the ode is $\cos(\color{red}\phi(z))$, not $\cos(\color{red}z)$, right? In order to integrate the ode, one must first multiply it by $\phi'(z)$; the result is basically kinetic energy+ potential energy, $\sim \phi'(z)^2+\sin^2\phi(z)=\text{const}$, I believe.

Comment: @Ed209 Thanks you for the hint. I tried to fix it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You have good eyes! Thanks you for the hint. I tried to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica can solve the ode in general

```
sol = DSolve[A ϕ''[z] == -Cos[ϕ[z]] Sin[ϕ[z]], ϕ,z];
Simplify[ϕ'[z] /. sol]
```

but there are two branches of solution `±ϕ[z]`!